# When exporting my code as a jar file,I'm getting the below error when my APP tries to unzip the jar file

Tags: java

ERROR

> ERROR Bundle [za.co.multichoice.eventtracker.logging] Error creating
>   bean with name
>   'org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#0':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'interfaces'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>   [com.soa.message.handler.HandlerFactory]

**LoggingHandlerFactory class**

```
package za.co.multichoice.eventtracker.logging;

import com.digev.fw.exception.GException;
import com.soa.message.handler.HandlerContext;
import com.soa.message.handler.HandlerFactory;
import com.soa.message.handler.HandlerRole;
import com.soa.message.handler.MessageHandler;

public class LoggingHandlerFactory implements HandlerFactory {

    public MessageHandler create(HandlerContext context, HandlerRole role)
      throws GException {

        return new LoggingHandler();

    }

}
```

OSGI xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- 
  Spring definition for the logging handler OSGi integration.
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <osgi:service interface="com.soa.message.handler.HandlerFactory">
        <osgi:service-properties>
            <entry key="name" value="examples.logging.factory"/>
            <entry key="scope" value="all"/>
            <entry key="role" value="provider"/>
        </osgi:service-properties>
        <bean class="za.co.multichoice.eventtracker.logging.LoggingHandlerFactory"/>
    </osgi:service> 

</beans>
```

Comment: *"Cannot find class [com.soa.message.handler.HandlerFactory]"* means that the jar file with that class is not on the classpath. Fix the classpath and try again.

Comment: You either need to package your code as a fat JAR, or include the relevant dependency JARs on the classpath.

Comment: How do you make you package ?

Comment: Hi Andreas, ManoDestra I checked my classpath and yes the jar file is include in the classpath file. I'm not sure I might be missing something else or what.

Comment: I'm exporting my package as a jar file I created my MANIFEST file manually then exported the jar file.